# Defining big query dbt sources with characters in table name?

Tags: google-bigquery, dbt

After reviewing both of the below resources:

- [Source configurations](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/source-configs)
- [BigQuery configurations](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/resource-configs/bigquery-configs)

I was unable to find an answer to this question:

Given a standard dbt project directory, I am defining a `sources.yml` which points to pre-existing bigquery tables that contain character names.

`sources.yml`:

```
version: 2

sources:
    - name: biqquery
      tables: 
        - name: `fa--task.dataset.addresses`
        - name: `fa--task.dataset.devices`
        - name: `fa--task.dataset.orders`
        - name: `fa--task.dataset.payments`
```

Using tilde as in ` was successful directly from a select statement:

```
(select * from `fa--task.dataset.orders`)
```

but is not recognized as valid yaml in sources.

The desired result would be something like:

```
{{ sources('bigquery','`fa--task.dataset.addresses`') }}
```

Edit: Updated source.yml as requested:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this!

```yml
version: 2

sources:
  - name: bigquery # are you sure you want to name it this? usually we name things after the data source, like 'stripe', or 'saleforce'
    schema: dataset
    database: fa--task
    tables: 
      - name: addresses
      - name: devices
      - name: orders
      - name: payments
```

Then in your models can do:

```
select * from {{ source('bigquery', 'addresses') }}
```

It might worth checking out the [guide on sources](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/building-a-dbt-project/using-sources/) to wrap your head around what's happening here, as well as the docs for [source properties](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/source-properties) which contains the list of the keys available under the `source:` keys.

Comment: This is a very, very helpful answer @Claire, but it doesn't work! I'm getting the following error now when I reference this using `source`:
Compilation Error in model stg_payments (models/dbt_project/staging/stg_payments.sql) Model 'model.my_new_project.stg_payments' (models/dbt_project/staging/stg_payments.sql) depends on a source named 'bigquery.payments' which was not found

Comment: That's odd — what does your `sources.yml` file look like now?

Comment: see edit in original question - screenshot at bottom.

Comment: That all looks fine to me. Is your `sources.yml` file in the `models/` directory?

Comment: It's under `models/sources/` and that is enabled in `dbt_project.yml`